# How to find out if a router or PC Wi-Fi is the reason for losing connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a PC (which never loses connection) connected by Ethernet to a router ([TP-LINK TL-WR842ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR842ND.html)) and a notebook connected by Wi-Fi.

From time to time there is loss of the connection—not only Internet, total loss of connection—on the notebook.

How do I find out the whether the reason for losing the connection is the router or the PC’s Wi-Fi?

Comment: WiFi is very prone to interference.  For example, running a microwave or unshielded kitchen appliances can cause a dropped connection.  Running a connectivity test on the notebook to both the router and to an internet address as well as a connectivity test (like repeated pings) from the hardwired desktop to the router would let you isolate the issue.  Check if Wifi channel has other competing APs, and if needed change to a different non-overlapping wifi channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolate the problem, as much as you can. Here is a list of something that could solve your problem:

1. Connect only the notebook to the router;
2. Remember that some cordless phone use the same frequency, 2.4-2.4835GHz in your case;
3. Other routers in the same channel, look for other networks that is using the same channel;
4. Problems with Wi-Fi network drivers;
5. Try to use your notebook in another Wi-Fi router or use your router with other Wi-Fi equipment, like a tablet or a smartphone;

Answer (score 1):

Simple.. when one is having issues ping the gateway from the other device (and from the device with issues), as well as you can ping one device from the other, and you can ping 8.8.8.8 (one of google's pingable IP addresses) to see if you have internet access

Comment: Also in my experience with TPlink.. They are junk and I bet it is the TP device that is causing the issue..

Answer (score 1):

To isolate the problem you should try to connect to a different WiFi signal that you know is working.  I always just set up a WiFi hotspot from my cell phone.  If you can get the internet on your notebook through the hotspot and not through your router, then you've isolated the problem to the router.

There are many reasons that your router may not be working, many of which are interference.  If you can eliminate interference, then the transceiver of your router may be bad.  The only way I know to fix that is to cable in to the router instead of using the WiFi, or get a new router.